# How to translate a circle to new centre?

Tags: circles, transformation

Consider that we have a circle drawn a round the **origin (0,0)**. That circle has some points drawn on its circumference. Each of those points has range and azimuth $(r,\theta)$, the **r** and **$\theta$** values of these points are calculate with responding to the **origin (0,0)**.

I want to move or translate that circle and its (on-circumference) points to a new center (x,y), the new center can be in any quadrant. Here is an image for more demonstration (consider that it was translated to the first quadrant):[image]

**The question is what is the new $(r, \theta)$ of each point with responding to the origin (0,0) after translation to the new center?**

Comment: What are your thoughts? Also, let me ask you a question: If a point $(x,y)$ in Cartesian coordinates is translated by $(a,b)$, what will be the coordinates of the new point? If you know that, then what is the Cartesian coordinates of, say, $a$? So, what is the $(r,\theta)$ (polar) coordinates of the translated $a$?

Comment: @Hamed for the first question ,for sure it will be (x+a, y+b). For the second question, Cartesian coordinates point (a) = (r,0) and for the translated (a) will be = (r+y,0+x), but the polar coordinate of the translated a will be :  r = square root of((r+y)squared + (0+x)squared)) and theta = inverse than (r+y/0+x)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a circle centered at the origin we have (taking $x$ axis on the right and $y$ axis upward and $\theta$ as indicated in the sketch):

$$x^2+y^2=R^2 \iff (x,y)=(R\sin \theta_0,R\cos\theta_0)$$

for a circle centered at $C=(x_C,y_C)$ we have:

$$(x-x_C)^2+(y-y_C)^2=R^2\iff (x,y)=(x_C+R\sin \theta_0,y_C+R\cos\theta_0)$$

Then the new polar coordinates are (using the [arctan2 function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2)) are :

- $r=\sqrt{(x_C+R\sin \theta_0)^2+(y_C+R\cos\theta_0)^2}$
- $\theta=\arctan2\left(\frac x y\right)=\arctan2\left(\frac {x_C+R\sin \theta_0}{y_C+R\cos\theta_0}\right)$

Comment: what is theta calculated from in that equation?

Comment: For clarity, $\theta$ in @gimusi's last equation should be $\theta_0$, as it was measured when the circle was at the origin. $(x,y)=(x_C+R\cos\theta_0,y_C+R\sin\theta_0)$. Then $\tan\theta=\frac{x}{y}=\frac{x_C+R\cos\theta_0}{y_C+R\sin\theta_0}$.

Comment: @Ahmed I'll add some detail.

Comment: @Andrei Yes I try to make more clear that part.

Comment: @gimusi what is θ0 denote for?

Comment: @Ahmed $\theta_0$ is the angle for the circle centered at the origin, I fix that

Comment: @gimusi you mean that $(theta)_0$ is the angle of the points in the circle centered at the origin?

Comment: @Ahmed Yes exactly and $\theta$ is the new angle.

Comment: oh, i see that you have changed it in the first equation

Comment: @Ahmed Yes indeed now it should be complete!

Comment: @Ahmed You are welcome! It was a plesure can help you in some way. Bye

Answer (score 1):

In general, expressions in polar form after a translation are not very elegant.

However, here is how you can derive the polar form of a circle that is not centered at the origin, $\mathbf{O}$.

Consider an arbitrary point $\mathbf{P}(r,\theta)$ on the (translated) circle whose [new] center is at $\mathbf{S}(r_0, \theta_0)$.

Then using the cosine rule on triangle $\mathbf{OPS}$, we have 
$$ r^2 + r_0^2 - 2r_0 r \cos(\theta - \theta_0) = R^2 $$

Thus we have an (implicit) formula for the translated circle which involves $r$ and $\theta$.

Rearranging this into descending powers of $r$, gives.
$$ r^2 -  2r_0 \cos(\theta - \theta_0) r  + (r_0^2 -R^2) = 0 $$.

Since this is a quadratic in $r$, and using the identity $\cos^2 \alpha + \sin^2 \alpha =1 $, we can solve for $r$.

This results in the more direct expression for $r$ in terms of $\theta$:

$$
r = r_0\cos(\theta-\theta_0)+\sqrt{R^2-r_0^2\sin^2(\theta-\theta_0)}
$$

For a diagram of this, see [here](http://www.nabla.hr/PC-RectPolarCooSys4.htm).

## #

Note that standard math notation is East + going anticlockwise. The OP's notation is North + clockwise. For this problem due to it all being in polar notation, using either convention will result in the same final expression.

Comment: "Consider an arbitrary point P(r,θ) on the circle whose [new] center is at  S(r0,θ0).", you mean that P is on the untranslated circle and the center of the translated circle is S(r0,θ0) ??  Or you mean that both points belongs to the translated circle

Comment: @Martin_Rberts another question, what is the reference from which theta was measured? from the +ve x axis or from the +ve y axis and in what direction does it increment? also what is R denoting for( i guess it is the line connecting between the S and P is not it)?

Comment: what is R denoting for( i guess it is the line connecting between the S and P is not it)?

Comment: Edited answer so that it now includes a link to a diagram.

Comment: i did not see it yet, but i think it is more easier from the beginning to add that link

Comment: One important thing that in your answer (and in the link you posted) that you proposed that i know the angel theta of the P point but, the question is about the r and theta of that point ?? i mean that the angle theta is not know for me so i cant you it in the solution

Comment: why the expressions in polar form after a translation are not very elegant ?